# UIViewController: Preferred way to handle Content scrolling behind transparent status bar

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, ios7, statusbar

With iOS 7 we get the fancy transparent/blurry status and navigation bars.
I saw many posts here on SO talking about the content being overlapped by the status bar.
I understand why this is happening and it's ok in my case.

Now, I was wondering since I don't have navigation bars in my app:
How shall I handle any content being scrolled behind the transparent status bar. 
(Note: By scrolling I mean real scrolling through content)

In my opinion it doesn't look nice if the status bar simply overlaps the content.
Is there an easy way to make it look "nicer"? Or do I have to play with offsets and manual blur to achieve a better look?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question, could you not place the background image to cover the entire screen and offset the scroll view y position by 20px (the height of the status bar).

Therefore you still get the nice effect of the transparent status bar but no content ever going under the bar itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes that's the approach i also have in mind. I thought there might be a nicer way to actually have the content scrolling behind the status bar, but with a nice blur effect.